# ¿De que forma se puede validar para que el usuario seleccione dos ckeckbox para poder ingresar?

Tags: android, validación, checkbox

Buen dia, tengo una aplicación en android y necesito que el usuario seleccione dos checkbox al momento de ingresar, de que forma lo puedo validar ? de que forma quedaria el boton en el .java[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias, anexo imagen

Comment: Define por favor si son checkbox individuales o es un grupo, agrega como lo tienes definido en tu .xml por favor. Recuerda revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el método `isChecked()` de la clase `CheckBox` para comprobar si ambos check box están marcados y entrar.

```
public void ingresar  (View view){
    if  (ckeck1.isChecked () && chek2.isChecked()){
        //código para ingresar
   }else {
        Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "Debe marcar las dos casillas para entrar", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show ();
   }
}
```